# Content is going outside of the margin

Tags: line-breaking

I'm trying to add sample content to my document, but it seems like whenever I use \texttt or \lstinline tags my content still goes out of the margin. Is there any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: Check out the url package.

Comment: So the issue is I need to add inline code, not just the URls

Comment: Please show the code that gives rise to the scrreenshot you posted.

Comment: @Mico I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! W need to see the code (copy from your editor) of small, but complete document, which produce showed compilation result, which we can test as it is. In its preamble should be loaded only to your problem relevant packages.

Comment: you should show code as text but as commented above the url package would help here (these are not url but the typesetting issues are the same)

Comment: I suggest you load the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package and replace, say, `\texttt{spring.datasource.driverClassName}` with `\path{spring.datasource.driverClassName}`.

Comment: The url package has been used for many things bsdies URLs.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551389/how-to-prevent-biburlnumpenalty-to-create-orphans-in-doi and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15950/hyphenation-of-long-java-identifiers for example.